# Search Ada Lib for open a file over http

Tags: ada

I'm searching for a Library which I can include in a program to open a file with a given internet address. Just like http://foobar.com/foobar.txt.

Like

```
Ada.Text_IO.Open (File, Ada.Text_IO.In_File, "bla.txt");
```

but which is not limited on local files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you aren't liable to find something with that exact interface, as Text_IO is a standard library and can't easily be extended by third parties in that way.

If your platform's underlying filesystem were to support HTTP, then it would work just like you want. I don't know of any platform that works that way however.

What you probably want as a general solution is [AWS (Ada Web Server)](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/aws/). A person could use that to implement a full-blown web server if they want, but it also contains HTTP client facilities. The HTTP client would be what you want (see AWS.Client). It would be a bit more work on your part than just making one standard API call, but probably no too much work.

Here's an example, cribbed from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/HTTP#Ada):

```
with Ada.Text_IO; 
use Ada.Text_IO; 
with AWS.Client;
with AWS.Response; 
procedure HTTP_Request is
begin
   Put_Line (AWS.Response.Message_Body (AWS.Client.Get (URL => "http://www.rosettacode.org")));
end HTTP_Request;
```

Answer (score 1):

Having used and implemented several HTTP clients, I would advise you to use an established and dedicated client. There are many intricacies to the HTTP standard that are not handled by naive implementations https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.

Consider using the Ada Bindings for a mature library like libCURL;  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ada95/